# Difference equation problem with trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus

[image: question]

Hello, I am trying to solve this.

I believe (a) yields

$y_{n+1}=arccot(0.5(cot(y_n)-tan(y_n)))$

For (b) onwards I am unsure how to tackle this question. I think that (b) might be a difference equation, but I'm unsure how to yield the correct answer from (a). I think if I was given pointers on (b) I could then go on to solve the rest of the parts.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: $$x_n=\cot y_n\implies \cot(y_{n+1})=\cot(2y_n)$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee can you please explain how you got this?

Comment: Use the double angle formula for $cot$

Comment: @claudeleibovici I don't follow this, can you explain please?

Comment: @user127700. Have a look to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula for double angle is $$\cot(2y)=\frac{\cot ^2(y)-1}{2 \cot(y) }$$ Then
$$2 \cot(2y)=\cot(y)-\frac{1}{\cot(y) }$$ I am sure that you can now take from here.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you explain how I would start (b)?